# Go to a specific location on web page when clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html

Hello so I am a beginner in javascript and html and I would like to know if it is possible to go to a specific location on a web page when pressing a button (without reloading the page) and I have no idea of how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Just add an id for each section in the webpage. Create hyperlinks with href=#id-of-the-section. So when you click on the hyperlink it will scroll to the particular section/element whose is mentioned

Comment: Do you want to click on a button and go to a link on the same page or a different page in the same site?

Comment: the same page if it is possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use hyperlinks to do that.

**Element target**

```
<div id="element_target">Content</div>
```

**Link to target**

```
<a id="link" href="#element_target">Go to content</a>
```

To enable **Smooth Scrolling**, add this to your CSS file

```
html {  
      scroll-behavior: smooth;  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your your answer the hyperlinks worked fine for me.

Answer (score 7):

The only thing that is coming to mind is a link like;

```
<a href="#yourContentIdHere">name you want to appear as the link here</a>


<div id="yourContentIdHere">
your awesome content
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer, helped a lot :-)

Comment: this wasn't working in my angular project

Answer (score 2):

You can also use this code if you ever going to use javascript.

For example when you don't want to put a link but a button like `<input type="button></input>`", just add `<input type="button" onclick="location.href='your desired url'"></input>`.